# AJAX HoverMenuExtender expands/displays on page load

Tags: asp.net

Anybody help me to resolve this issue ?
I am displaying one grid on hover of linkbutton using AJAX hovermenu extender.
But when page is loading first time or on postback, that grid is displaying.

Below is the code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkItm" runat="server" Text="Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<AjaxToolKit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme2" runat="Server" TargetControlID="lnkItm"
PopupControlID="PopupMenu" HoverCssClass="popupHover" PopupPosition="Right" OffsetX="0"
OffsetY="0" PopDelay="50" />
<asp:Panel CssClass="PopupMenu" ID="PopupMenu" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" Width="100px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
...
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.It will hide the popup when the page loads.

```
<style type="text/css">

    .PopupMenu

    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```